# How to create two different frame on a same master

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create two LabelFrame in tkinter which are supposed to take opposite place in the window. Simply one must be place on left and the other on the right.

I have tried some code but eventhough i place them on the same master the second frame takes place on the first frame. Here i share the code. I put the `LabelFrame`s in the `MainScreen` method.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        # Screen Widgets

        self.MainScreen()

        # Create MainLoop
        self.root.mainloop()
    
    def MainScreen(self):

        # Create Mainscreen on a frame
        self.addData = LabelFrame(self.root,text = "Insert some data",padx = 50, pady = 50)
        self.addData.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 20,pady = 20,columnspan = 2)

        text = Text(self.addData,height = 10,width = 40)
        text.grid(row = 0, column = 0,rowspan = 4)

        b = Button(self.addData,text = "a button")
        b.grid( row = 0,column = 1,sticky = N + S )

        self.secondFrame = LabelFrame(self.root,text = "Second Frame")
        self.secondFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

        text1 = Text(self.secondFrame,height = 10,width = 40)
        text1.grid(row = 0, column = 1,rowspan = 4)
        



m = Main()
```

Here i share the output.

[image: output]

I just need to have two frames that separated from each other. I need the second `LabelFrame` to act like first `LabelFrame`

Comment: You want both frames to be of equal size ? one at left and the other at right ?

Comment: Yes i want it like that.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please accept if its what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is giving me the correct output as mentioned

```
    self.addData = LabelFrame(self.root,text = "Insert some data", padx=20,pady=20)
    self.addData.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

    text = Text(self.addData,height = 10,width = 40)
    text.grid(row = 0, column = 0,rowspan = 4)

    self.secondFrame = LabelFrame(self.root,text = "Second Frame",padx=20,pady=20)
    self.secondFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

    text1 = Text(self.secondFrame,height = 10,width = 40)
    text1.grid(row = 0, column = 1,rowspan = 4)
```